# An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

Now I am implementing a trial server resource for study and there is the following problem with the fact that when I send a request along with an access token to it, I get an error *An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set*.
Judging by the error trace, there is some error with JSON parsing or JWT decoding.

My authorization server configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class ServerSecurityConfiguration {
    
    @Bean 
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
            );

        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean 
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean 
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean 
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("food-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/food-client")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope("read")
                .scope("write")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean 
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() { 
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean 
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .authorizationEndpoint("/authorize")
                .tokenEndpoint("/token")
                .tokenIntrospectionEndpoint("/introspect")
                .tokenRevocationEndpoint("/revoke")
                .jwkSetEndpoint("/jwks")
                .build();
    }
}
```

My resource server:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityApiConfig {
    
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    private String jwkSetUri;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/api/dishes/**")
                .hasAuthority("SCOPE_read")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                    .jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder())
            );
        return http.build();
    }
    
     @Bean
        public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
            return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).build();
        }
}
```

Resource Server's properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://127.0.0.1:9000
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://127.0.0.1:9000/jkws
```

Error when trying to access authorization server:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:103) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:87) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:167) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:96) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't parse remote JWK set: Invalid JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:313) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.get(RemoteJWKSet.java:437) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.proc.JWSVerificationKeySelector.selectJWSKeys(JWSVerificationKeySelector.java:157) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.selectKeys(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:283) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:354) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:303) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:154) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Invalid JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.JSONObjectUtils.parse(JSONObjectUtils.java:126) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.JSONObjectUtils.parse(JSONObjectUtils.java:83) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet.parse(JWKSet.java:351) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:311) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar:9.24.4]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The error explicitly says that the problem is with the JWK-set. Have you tried to just remove the property (just keep `issuer-uri`, `jwk-set-uri` should be retrieved from the OIDC config)? Have you tried with another authorization-server (Keycloak, Auth0, Cognito or whatever)?

Comment: I did not use it, because I want to implement my own authorization server

Comment: This is not incompatible with using one to check if the problem is in your authorization-server impl or resource-server config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

1. You need to get the server's oidc configuration and see what algorithms it supports. I got this from endpoint {host}/.well-known/openid-configuration. Find the naming of the algorithm in the configuration, in my case it was RS256.
2. Next, I just reworked jwtEncoder by adding the jws algorithm
3. And I deleted property spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri from my application.properties

And everything worked

Code:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityApiConfig {

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
private String jwkSetUri;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/api/dishes/**")
            .hasAuthority("SCOPE_read")
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                .jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder())
        );
    return http.build();
}

 @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder
                .withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri)
                .jwsAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256).build();
    }
```

}

Comment: If your authorization-server is OIDC, spring-boot should infer the `openid-configuration` from `issuer-uri` and provide a `JwtDecoder` bean correctly configured for you. Just try without `JwtDecoder` bean in your conf (and without `jwk-set-uri` in your properties file)

Comment: Additionally, you might be missing a few things in your resource-server configuration (CORS config and maybe sessions and CSRF protection disabling). I have written a [set of tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) which are written for Keycloak (because I don't want to maintain clients and user management screens), but adapting it to any other OIDC authorization-server is just a matter of editing `issuer-uri` and private claim(s) holding authorities in properties file.